# How to put an error under MaterialSpinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am using [MaterialSpinner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7712#!description) and I want to put an error under the spinner if nothing gets selected,
 [image: spinner error]

here is what I tried so far :

```
MaterialSpinner spinnerniveau =  findViewById(R.id.Niveau_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.niveaux_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerniveau.setAdapter(adapter);
 if(spinnerniveau.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty())
         {
             spinnerniveau.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_niveau));
         }
         else
         {
          //getting the string
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do that, assuming your adapter are String:

```java
String selected = (String) spinnerniveau.getSelectedItem();

if (null == selected){
    spinnerniveau.setError("Put error text");
}
```

Comment: i am still getting this error     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.tiper.MaterialSpinner.getSelectedItem()' on a null object reference

Comment: That error means that you object **spinnerniveau** is null, therefore, this line: `MaterialSpinner spinnerniveau =  findViewById(R.id.Niveau_spinner);` returns null. Which is strange given your code sample, because it will be also null when setting the adapter. I mean here: `spinnerniveau.setAdapter(adapter);`. If so, then check that you are inflating the correct layout and that it has a MaterialSpinner with id **Niveau_spinner**

Comment: Now that I wrote that, I realize that ID must be all be **lowercase** that could be your error

Comment: thanks! I did a stupid mistake, declared the spinner twice and I didn't notice it